# Delete recursively some file without certain extensions

Tags: windows, powershell, prompt, delete-file

I've some big folders with many subfolders and i need to delete all files that aren't image 
jpeg|tiff|bmp|png|eps|gif and keep only that files with these extensions.

I ask something with windows powershell or prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
@echo off
set ROOTDIR=E:\Testdel\
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir %ROOTDIR% /s /b /a-d ^|findstr /vile ".jpeg .jpg .gif .png .tiff .bmp .eps .cdr .cpt .psd"') do del "%%F"
```

Comment: Hello, what would be the change to have it as variable root folder(so you could put it in any kind of folder) and run it from that folder recursively? Thank you